# db_query and condition in custom field

Tags: nodes, entities

on my website, i have articles. All of them have custom field named event date. I want to select 50 nodes of type article with event date value "2016-07-29 16:25:00". How to do this?

I tried following code, but it looks like query cannot find any custom field column.

```
$nids = db_select('node', 'n')
->fields('n', array('nid'))
->fields('n', array('type'))
->fields('n', array('field_event_date'))
->condition('n.type', 'article')
->condition('n.field_event_date', "2016-07-29 16:25:00")
->range(0, 50)
->execute()
->fetchCol();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot find any custom fields because fields created using the field API are not stored in the *node* table, but in a different table. In code, you should use the [`EntityFieldQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) class.

```
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->fieldCondition('field_event_date', 'value', '2016-07-29 16:25:00')
    ->fieldOrderBy('field_event_date', 'value', 'ASC')
                    ->execute();

  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($entities['node']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module which wouldn't require you to do any coding to achieve this.

- Enable views
- Ebale views UI

**Add a new view** and select **Create a Block**

[image]

in **FIELDS** add all the fields you want

in **FILTER CRITERIA** **add your event date field**

[image]

Go to Blocks `/admin/structure/block`

- Under **Disabled** look for your View Block, click configure.
- Assign your block a region and in Visibility settings you may want to only show it in certain pages.

[image]

Comment: Another good approach. However less flexible than previous answer.

Comment: Aight, fair enough, no vote up for all my efforts? =(

Comment: I have not fully registred account, but i will vote up after i complete registration!